# How do I do multiple toolbars at the top of a window in SwiftUI on MacOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, menu, toolbar

I have something like this and both toolbars are on the same line.  I want them both stacked on top of each other.  One toolbar on top of the other:

```
struct ToolbarView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm: DrawModel
    init( _ dm: DrawModel ) { self.dm = dm }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{ }
        .toolbar
        {   
            AddToolbarItems( dm, toolbar1 )
        }   

        .toolbar {
            AddToolbarItems( dm,  toolbar2 )
        }
    }
}
```

To be clearer the toolbar buttons are showing up like this. Where TB is a toolbar and the 2.1 is Toolbar 2 item 1. etc

```
TB2.1   TB2.2  TB1.1   TB1.2
```

Like this instead:

```
TB1.1   TB1.2
TB2.1   TB2.2
```

Edit-1

[image: My output from WorkingDog's Suggestion]

Answer (score 0):

how about you try `AddToolbarItems( dm,  toolbar2 )` **first** followed by `AddToolbarItems( dm,  toolbar1 )`, to give you what you `like this instead: TB1.1 TB1.2 TB2.1 TB2.2`.

```
VStack{ }
.toolbar {
    AddToolbarItems( dm, toolbar2 )
}
.toolbar {
    AddToolbarItems( dm,  toolbar1 )
}
```

Alternatively:

```
 .toolbar {
     AddToolbarItems( dm, toolbar1 )
     AddToolbarItems( dm, toolbar2 )
 }
```

EDIT-1:

If you have only the four items mentioned,
then to display 2 sets of 2 items, you could try this:

```
 .toolbar {
     VStack(spacing: 1) {
         HStack(spacing: 1) {
            AddToolbarItems( dm, toolbar1 )
         }
         HStack(spacing: 1) {
            AddToolbarItems( dm, toolbar2 )
         }
     }
 }
```

Better still, have the `HStack` in your `AddToolbarItems`.

However, if you have many items, there may not be enough space for all of them.
Note, the height of the `.toolbar` is determined by the system and cannot be changed.
You can of course create your own custom toolbar, without using the `.toolbar` modifier, very easy to do and you can choose whatever size you want.

EDIT-2

Here is my full test code that works for me.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ToolbarView()
    }
}

struct ToolbarView: View {
//    @ObservedObject var dm: DrawModel
    // no need for init()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {}
            .toolbar {
                VStack(spacing: 1) {
                    AddToolbarItems( ["TB1.1", "TB1.2"] )
                    AddToolbarItems( ["TB2.1", "TB2.2"] )
                }
            }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func AddToolbarItems(_ arr: [String]) -> some View {
        HStack (spacing: 1) {
            ForEach(arr, id: \.self) { item in
                Button(item){ }//.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot when using my code with Button and systemImage.

[image]

Comment: Hey WD, Sorry I edited by original and put my toolbar output in code blocks to protect the returns.  I'll try the additional HStacks and spacing.  Give me a second.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these patterns worked.  I tried a couple of others as well based on this pattern.  I have plenty of room on the screen, bar and window.  Maybe I need to change the total height of the toolbar space.  Then possibly one of these patterns will work.

Comment: My `EDIT-1` answer works well for me. 
Also, show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [Minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I can only guess what your `AddToolbarItems` does.
Show just enough code to replicate your issue when we compile and run it as is.

Comment: AddToolbarItems returns a standard view with a few buttons as icons.  toolbar1 is simply an array of menu items with the resource name being used for the icon.  I can see if I can create a simplified version of it.  In the mean time I'll remove AddToolbarItems and put in some simple buttons.  Oh, I found  ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .primaryAction ) which I thought would allow me to group and name the toolbars with placement but there is no MacOS placement for a second toolbar at the top.

Comment: updated my answer with my test code.

Comment: OK, simplified my code to 2 .toolbars.  Each with A circle button and a square button.  Like this: Button( "Testing2", systemImage: "circle" ).  The two buttons are side by side.  So, maybe something else affecting it.  I'll try your updated Edit 2 next.

Comment: I updated my original request with the output from your suggestion.  It's definitely not what I'd want as it's not standard GUI on a Macintosh.  BUT, I do see that your method is working.  There must be something else blocking the standard behavior.

Comment: Not clear what you are saying, the picture you show is not what you want?
 You don't want to have the "Like this instead:"
 with `TB1.1` and `TB1.2` then below that, the
 `TB2.1` and `TB2.2`. Are you saying now, you want all items to be displayed
 side by side?

Comment: No, the icons on cramped vertically and have been shrunk in size.  They are very close to the top and bottom of the display area.  I changed your example code to display the icons instead of text so I could see what was happening.

Comment: Like I said before (EDIT-1), there may not be enough space for all of the items.

Comment: Understood, I took that as left to right not top to bottom.

Comment: @Marcy would be useful if you looked at this.  Even with all the suggestions I can't get this to work correctly.  Two lines with proper spacing to match MacOS guidelines.